# React flexbox element not adjusting to width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create slide carousel, it's almost done, but I've got an issue with adjusting arrows to the image.

When checking if the website is responsive the div inside flexbox stops shrinking and stays in one position. It looks okay, because there is overflow: hidden. The problem is with arrows, they stay in the same position, so they disappear.

My issue is with adjusting them, so when the website is displayed in smaller resolution, there is still possibility to change slide.

I hope I've explained it in detail.

css:

```
    .header{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    border-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header__box{
}

.right-arrow{ 
position: relative;
bottom: 350px;
left: 900px;
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: #000;
 z-index: 10;
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;
}

.left-arrow{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 350px;
    left: 80px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.slide{
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transform: scale(1.00);
}

.slide.active{
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transform: scale(1.00);
}

.image{
}
```

code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import {HeaderData} from './HeaderData'
import {FaArrowAltCircleRight, FaArrowAltCircleLeft} from 'react-icons/fa'

const Header = ({slides}) => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
    const length = slides.length

    const nextSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1)
    }

    const prevSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === 0? length -1 : current -1 )
    }

    console.log(current)

    return (
    <div className='header'> 
        <div className='header__box'>
            {HeaderData.map((slide, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className={index === current? 'slide active' : 'slide'}>
                            {index === current ? <img src={slide.image} className='image' alt='shoe photo'/> : null}
                        </div>
                        
                    )
            })}
             <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className='left-arrow' onClick={prevSlide}/>
            <FaArrowAltCircleRight className='right-arrow' onClick={nextSlide}/>   
            </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40vh;
  border-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header__box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.right-arrow,
.left-arrow {
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.slide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

img.image {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

and this:

```
const Header = ({ slides }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length
  const HeaderData = [{ image: test }, { image: foto }, { image: foto2 }];

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header__box">
        <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide} />
        {HeaderData.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <div className={index === current ? "slide active" : "slide"}>
              {index === current ? (
                <img src={slide.image} className="image" alt="shoe photo" />
              ) : null}
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <FaArrowAltCircleRight className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

So the idea above is to put the slides in between the left and right arrows.
So this part of the code shown above:

```
<div className="header__box">
  <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide} />
  {HeaderData.map((slide, index) => {
    return (
      <div className={index === current ? "slide active" : "slide"}>
        {index === current ? (
          <img src={slide.image} className="image" alt="shoe photo" />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  })}
  <FaArrowAltCircleRight className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />
</div>
```

What this allows us to do is to apply `display: flex` on the `.header__box` div surrounding the slides and the arrows. This makes the positioning of the arrows easier. The most important part is to also set `align-items: center` on `.header__box`, so the arrows are put in the middle respective to the container.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-allen-dhqow?file=/src/App.js)